# calculate if the timestamp is greater or smaller than current time

Tags: elasticsearch

In the elasticsearch, the document contains parameter validTo (timestamp). Considering the value, I would like to calculate the document status; if validTo is smaller than current time, the status should be 'expired', otherwise, the status should be 'active'.

Here is the example request for script (with status calculation part missing):

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
            "userId": "1"
        }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "validTo": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc[\u0027validTo\u0027].value" <-- example doc['validTo'] = "2019-01-05T10:17:35.000Z"
      }
    },
    "status": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        // here the status should be calculated depending on the time condition
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: painless exposes java.time.Instant, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.4/painless-api-reference-shared-java-time.html#painless-api-reference-shared-Instant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to calculate the status with the following script:

```
"script_fields": {
    "status": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
        long now = new Date().getTime(); 
        String fieldDate = doc["validTo"].value.toString(); 
        ZonedDateTime fieldZDT = ZonedDateTime.parse(fieldDate); 
        long nowZDT = new Date().getTime(); 
        String nowString = params['now']; 
        long validToLong = doc["validTo"].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli(); 
        long timeDiff = validToLong - now; 
        String status = timeDiff > 0 ? "VALID" : "EXPIRED"; 
        status
        """
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, i did my best to solve this problem, but i faced a lot to get current `ZonedDateTime` inside script source, eventually; solved it.

I know it looks silly somehow, but it works properly as long as you don't care about timezone.

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "status": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
        // get current date as string
        String now = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        // add default timeZoned as string to be accepted in ZonedDateTime
        now += ".000Z";
        // get field value as string
        String fieldDate = doc['Order Date'].value.toString();
        // convert both; fieldDate and today into zdt
        ZonedDateTime fieldZDT = ZonedDateTime.parse(fieldDate);
        ZonedDateTime nowZDT = ZonedDateTime.parse(now);
        // make comparsion
        return fieldZDT.isBefore(nowZDT)? "expired": "active";
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried it, and it works for me.